# How to change master of an existing slide in Keynote 6.0?

Tags: keynote, iwork

In Keynote 5.x there was a toolbar button where I could change the master of an existing slide. This would keep the content of the slide, but would change the layout to the new master.

[image]

I can not find this functionality in Keynote 6.x anymore. I tried to configure the toolbar - but no "Master" button is there. I looked through all menues. And even the context menu of the slide.

Any hints where this functionality is gone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah! A few more minutes of "seeking" - and I found out where Apple moved the functionality.

For all desperate - here the solution:

1. Make sure you clicked on the slide-overview (on the left), so that the slide gets a yellow border
   [image]
2. Then far-away on the right select the "Format" button. Then below it you will see the current master slide for the selected slide. With a small grey triangle on the right. Click this triangle and a pop over will allow you to change the master of the current slide.
   [image]

Hope this helps someone in the future...

Comment: Thank you! That's crazy — should be a right-click option.

Answer (score 0):

I found I also had to delete the background on the imported slide.  I clicked the background, clicked the Unlock button on the Arrange panel, and then hit the delete key to delete the background.